# How can I solve System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException using SpeechRecognizer UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, speech-recognition

I'm getting a System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070490) using SpeechRecognizer.

I've read online that this error might be caused by a capability not being enabled or that the manifest is corrupt.

I have Internet (Client) and Microphone enabled, I also tried a clean manifest file, but it results in the same error message.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? This is an UWP app and I'm using Windows 10 Build 1709.

**My code:**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition;

namespace SpeechRecognitionRPi
{
    class SpeechHandling
    {
        public async void StartRecognition()
        {
            // Create an instance of SpeechRecognizer.
            var speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();

            // Compile the dictation grammar by default.
            await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();

            // Start recognition.
            SpeechRecognitionResult speechRecognitionResult = await speechRecognizer.RecognizeWithUIAsync();

            // Do something with the recognition result.
            var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(speechRecognitionResult.Text, "Text spoken");
            await messageDialog.ShowAsync();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by enabling the English-US language in Windows, you also need to install the speech module from Language options.